# Python key binding: TypeError: Takes no arguments(1 given)

Tags: python, tkinter

I apologize for asking this. I started learning python today, and I've searched around on SO and it *seems* like my problem can be solved pretty simply, but I keep having issues. In my current code:

```
master = Tk()

master.wm_title("V3")
w = Label(master, text="Code:")
w.pack()
master.resizable(width=False, height=False)
e = Entry(master, width = 35, justify = CENTER)
master.geometry('{}x{}'.format(240, 235))
e.pack()
e.focus_set()

def decode():
        textField.configure(state="normal")
        textField.delete(1.0,END)
        hint = e.get()
        for i, c in enumerate(hint):
                if i<5:
                    textField.insert(END,cypher1[c])
                if i>=5:
                    textField.insert(END,cypher2[c])
        master.clipboard_clear()
        master.clipboard_append(textField.get("1.0",'end-1c'))
        textField.configure(state="disabled")
        copyLabel.config(text = "Code Copied!")


b = Button(master, text = "Generate and Copy Key", width = 25, height = 2, command = decode)
b.pack()

textField = Text(master, height=3, width=35)
textField.pack()
copyLabel = Label(master, text="")
copyLabel.pack()
master.bind('<Return>', decode)


mainloop()
```

it works great!
...Except when I try to hit enter. Then it results in
`TypeError: decode() takes no arguments (1 given)`
 I've tried changing it to

```
master.bind('<Return>', decode())
```

and although it doesn't throw the error, it just doesn't do anything. I suspect my lack of objects is probably causing a problem.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks a ton.

Comment: maybe define `decode` as taking an argument. The problem with `master.bind('<Return>', decode())` is that you are binding the *value returned by `decode`, which is `None`.

Comment: Most references that document the `bind` command explain about the argument that is passed to the bound function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.bind() passes `event` to the function:

`def decode(event=None):`
or `def decode(*_):` which will eat any number of arguments

Comment: @AON I think in your case you're getting self (you could test it by printing the `type(event)` inside decode, but you're not using it either way, so you could even do `def decode(_):`

Comment: @TemporalWolf3 Actually `def decode(event)` and `def decode(_)` both worked for the key bind, but they broke the button click. in this case, giving the same thing, `TypeError: decode() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)`.

Comment: @TemporalWolf3 Ah I see. That worked like a charm. Thanks again!